# How can I make each image its own target for a modal window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've written this function that maps images from an array. This is being done in Next.js with react-bootstrap. This function is working how I want it to, but **I'd like to have each image to have an `onClick` function that opens itself into a new modal window.**

I'm using react-bootstrap, and they have a Modal component that works exactly how I want it to, so I don't really need help with the CSS or creating an actual modal window, I just need to figure out how to make each mapped image target itself for the image source in the popup window.

```
export default function Illustration() {
  let armArray = ['arms_1', 'arms_2', 'arms_3', 'arms_4', 'arms_5', 'arms_6','arms_7'].map(image => {
    return (
      <img 
        key={image}
        src={`/illus_assets/anatomy/${image}@0.1x.png`}
        className={styles.imgIllus}
      />
    )
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Col xs={12} sm={{ span: 10, offset: 1 }} lg={{ span: 10, offset: 2 }}>
        <Row>
          {armArray}
        </Row>
        <Row>
        
        </Row>
      </Col>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onClick funtion on the image and pass the event object.
Create a single common Modal using react-bootstrap with a placeholder for images.
eg: `<img src={imgUrl} alt="modal-image">`

And everytime an image is clicked get the img src from the `event.target` and pass it as props or set to a state value from where you can use this value in Modal as `imgUrl`.

As you said you dont need any Modal html or css, I'm not explaining them here.

Hope this would give you clarity

```js
export default function Illustration() {
    const [modalImgUrl, setModalImgUrl] = useState(null);
    
    const showImgModal = e => {
        setModalImgUrl(e.target.src)
    }
    
    let armArray = ['arms_1', 'arms_2', 'arms_3', 'arms_4', 'arms_5', 'arms_6','arms_7'].map(image => {
        return (
            <img 
                key={image} 
                src={`/illus_assets/anatomy/${image}@0.1x.png`}
                className={styles.imgIllus} 
                onClick={showImgModal}
            />
        )
    });
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Col xs={12} sm={{ span: 10, offset: 1 }} lg={{ span: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                <Row>
                    {armArray}
                </Row>
                <Row>

                </Row>
            </Col>  
        </Layout>
    );
}
```